# Fix for Vs Code Server Cannot Find Module Error

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, server

So Im' trying to build from the source from the repo https://github.com/cdr/code-server

And I'm getting the error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584

   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/gitpod/path/to/output/build/out/vs/server/main.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
```

When I run `node ~/path/to/output/build/out/vs/server/main.js`.

I have already ran `yarn build 1.39.2 1.0.0` and cloned and installed.
I am using linux.

Did anyone else find a solution for this?

Comment: Did you run `yarn install` inside of the project directory?

Comment: @Jacob Yes, I already ran `yarn install` inside the directory beforehand and after which does not fix the issue either.

Comment: Btw I am indeed using gitpod for testing purposes only, I do have a real system.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have this issue

Comment: Did you happen to find a fix for this?